# How to avoid an account in a period

Tags: mysql

Here is the data

```
username | datetime
chan     | 2016-02-25
Ivy      | 2016-02-25
chan     | 2016-02-26
Ivy      | 2016-02-26
chan     | 2016-02-27
Ivy      | 2016-02-27
chan     | 2016-02-28
Ivy      | 2016-02-28
```

How to select all data but avoid some one in a period like I don't need chan in 2016-02-26 and 2016-02-27, the result should be:

```
username | datetime
chan     | 2016-02-25
Ivy      | 2016-02-25
Ivy      | 2016-02-26
Ivy      | 2016-02-27
chan     | 2016-02-28
Ivy      | 2016-02-28
```

Comment: Please learn how to write `where` clause in a sql query. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: I know how where works, but do you know how to filter a data between a period of a select data from period without subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT username, datetime FROM table_name WHERE username, datetime NOT IN(
   SELECT username, datetime FROM table_name
   WHERE username = 'chan' 
   AND datetime BETWEEN 2016-02-26 and 2016-02-27
);
```

OR

You can also do like this query but in this query you put hardcoded value in `where clause`.

```
SELECT username, datetime 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (username, datetime) NOT IN(('chan','2016-02-26'),('chan', '2016-02-27'));
```

Comment: All I know is subquery too, but if possible I really don't want to use it, performance  issue

Comment: @Chan i have edited my answer but in this query you can write hardcoded value in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make a set of (username,datetime) pair (i.e. a restricted list).

```
SELECT
username,
`datetime`
FROM your_table
WHERE (username,`datetime`) NOT IN (('chan','2016-02-26'),('chan','2016-02-27'));
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ae738/1/0)

Sample input:

```
username | datetime
chan     | 2016-02-25
Ivy      | 2016-02-25
chan     | 2016-02-26
Ivy      | 2016-02-26
chan     | 2016-02-27
Ivy      | 2016-02-27
chan     | 2016-02-28
Ivy      | 2016-02-28
```

Sample Output:

```
username | datetime
chan     | 2016-02-25
Ivy      | 2016-02-25
Ivy      | 2016-02-26
Ivy      | 2016-02-27
chan     | 2016-02-28
Ivy      | 2016-02-28
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
  $sql="select username from table where datetime<='$startdatelimit' and datetime>='$enddatelimit'";
```

"=" includes both date limit.

You can remove "=" if not needed.